# How to dramatically increase the speed of xsltproc command?

Tags: xml, performance, xslt, xslt-1.0

This is the format of my XML data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rowdata>
  <row Id="1" type="1" data="text" ... />
  <row Id="2" type="2" data="text" parent="1" ... />
  <row Id="3" type="1" data="text" ... />
  <row Id="4" type="1" data="text" ... />
  <row Id="5" type="2" data="text" parent="4" ... />
  ...
```

And this is my XSL sheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="iso-8859-1"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
<xsl:template match="/rowdata">
  <xsl:for-each select="row">
    <xsl:if test="@Id = 10000">
      <xsl:value-of select="@data"/><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Facts:

1. I cannot change the XML data
2. I can change the XSL sheet
3. There are many rows in the XML data
4. The for-each selector can match only one row

Problem:

1. This command:  `xsltproc input.xls input.xml`  is very slow. Execution takes about 10 seconds for a single run (and many need to be made)

Already tried:

1. Researched if xsltproc can be made faster (multi-threaded run) - it cannot
2. Researched if there was any bottleneck with the hardware - there is not (NVMe on very fast 16 threads CPU)
   At first I thought it would take a long time to read a 1GB file. It does not, it is only xsltproc processing that takes time

Three questions:

1. Does this XSLT stylesheet look optimized?
2. Is there a way to "terminate the search (i.e. cancel further read) when the record is found"?
3. How can I dramatically increase the speed of the command above?

Comment: Could you split your XML into several pieces, and run several processors? I am wondering if that would allow more efficient use of CPU cores.

Comment: @halfer interesting idea, but how?

Comment: Hmm, I just spotted what it is doing - isn't it looking for rows where id=10000? If so, could you preprocess the file to remove lines that do contain `<row` but don't contain `Id="10000"`?

Comment: If that is not workable for whatever reason, then yes, I wonder if splitting the XML would be worth thinking about. That was more a "design prompt" remark rather than a "here's a piece of code". It looks like your query does not need parents/children to be in the same file, so perhaps you could pre-process this XML to split however many records you have into, say, four equal pieces. Could you try this manually and run four `xsltproc` commands in parallel, one per piece, as an experiment?

Comment: Thank you @halfer. The first idea won't work (filter on ID, as single ID's need to be found from the file). The second - split parents/children may work. And the third (split the file in total + parallel) may work too. Great ideas, thank you. You could post it as an answer if you like.

Answer (score 1):

What are you including in your 10 seconds? Does this include compiling the stylesheet and/or parsing/loading the source document, or is it purely the XSLT execution time?

I would expect that building an in-memory tree representation of your 900Mb input file is what is taking most of the time (10 seconds would be pretty fast for that operation). If you need to run the stylesheet many times, then the best way of improving performance will be to only build the source tree once and re-use it. But you then won't be able to run directly from the command line.

In principle you can speed up this kind of stylesheet by using keys:

```
<xsl:key name="k" match="row" use="@Id"/>
<xsl:template match="/rowdata">
  <xsl:value-of select="key('k', 10000)/@data"/>
</xsl:template>
```

However, that's only going to work if you can ensure that the key index is only built once, and is then used repeatedly. At this stage I can't tell you how this might work in xsltproc, because it's all getting processor-specific.

You can terminate the search after the first hit simply by adding the predicate `[1]`. But you're looking for bigger gains than that.

Comment: Hi Michael. Thank you. 10 seconds as measured by this command; `time xsltproc input.xls input.xml` ('real' time output). Not sure about what happens in the background thanks to xsltproc. Where can I add the predicate [1] ? I am kind of stuck with xsltproc unless I can easily swap it out for another tool. Thanks again.

Comment: So long as you run each transformation as a separate command from the command line, you are going to incur the costs of parsing/building the source document tree each time, and that's what's taking so long. So you need to change the approach. It's then a question of understanding what your technology constraints are; I'm reluctant to suggest a different design without a better understanding of the requirements.

Comment: The constraints are mostly the ones mentioned above, though I could try and pre-process the XML if it would help. It's a large flat file (1GB or more) with row lines as records. I do need to many searches through it. From what you are you saying, some things come to mind; 1) somehow pre-process the XML to make it more suitable for quick searching/indexing, 2) try and read multiple records at the same time, this may work as in one of the runs I need to find only the children (Id="2" .... parent="1"), 3) perhaps the best idea so far would be to split the parents and children into separate files?

Comment: Sorry, SO really isn't the right vehicle for this kind of discussion; we can't progress this in short comments. I suggest you raise it on xsl-list at mulberrytech which is much more open to design discussions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there can be only one row where `Id` is 1000, you could do simply:

```
<xsl:template match="/rowdata">
    <xsl:value-of select="row[@Id=1000]/@data"/>
</xsl:template>
```

I don't know if this will "dramatically increase the speed of the command".

Comment: Thank you for the simplified XSL! The timing is the same.

Comment: Does removing the `<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />` instruction make any difference?

Comment: Thanks! It seems to make it slower still :) Factor 1.2-1.4x